# How to modify a standard class t2-medium RI to a t2-large RI in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I tried to modify my t2.medium standard Reserver Instance(RI). In the modify window, I chose availability zone, instance type(t2.large) and clicked continue, but not able to modify.

How to proceed to upgrade my RI to a higher footprint RI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely can't upgrade your RI. Read the guide [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-modify-reserved-instance/).

You might be able to merge to RIs into a larger RI according to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-modifying.html). However I suggest you reach out to AWS sales to confirm this before buying another RI.

You can try to sell that RI and buy another in the RI market. When you buy a new RI there are many different types, some you can more easily upgrade. Have a reas about the RI types before you buy the next one.

Comment: If I buy another t2.medium standard RI, can I merge both my t2.mediums(2x2=4) to make it a t2.large?

Comment: See updated answer. I think so, but I don't know for sure, so suggest you ask AWS sales.

Comment: 2 RIs can be merged into a large RI if only those two had been bought at the same time.